# jQuery .blur() event not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a simple login form like below, with an attached jQuery script. I'm trying to make some simple client-side form validation using jQuery. I can't seem to get the blur event to fire, however. I can't think of what I'm doing wrong, I've tried using '.on('blur', fn(){})' but that doesn't work either. Please help!

Here's my HTML file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>DMIT 222 - Catalogue Project: Admin Login</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styles/divs.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styles/fonts.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styles/tags.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styles/tables.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/forms.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script src="../scripts/loginFormValidation.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <header>
                <h1>Ship Catalogue</h1>
            </header>
            <div id="mainContent">
                <form id="LoginForm" name="LoginForm" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
                    <div class="FormRow"><label for="Username">Username:</label><input type="text" name="Username" id="Username" /><p id="userErrors"><?php echo $userErrors; ?></p></div>
                    <div class="FormRow"><label for="Password">Password:</label><input type="password" name="Password" id="Password" /><p id="passwordErrors"><?php echo $passwordErrors; ?></p></div>
                    <div class="FormRow"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login!" /></div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <footer>
                <a href="http://www.logicanddesign.ca/">Site Developed by Logic &amp; Design</a>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here's the loginFormValidation.js script:

```
$("#Username").blur(function(e){
    alert();
    if ($("#Username").val() == "") {
        $("#userErrors").text("Username must be entered!");
    }
});

$("#Password").blur(function(e){
    if ($("#Password").val() == "") {
        $("#passwordErrors").text("Password must be entered!");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either add your jquery blur code inside

```
$(document).ready(function() { ...// your blur code here }
```

OR
at bottom of your page above closing **body** tag like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//your blur code
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: This worked, thank you! I tried window.onload, but something went wrong so I assumed I was on the wrong track. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

You need to wrap your events inside jQuery's document.ready function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#Username").blur(function(e){
       alert();
        if ($("#Username").val() == "") {
            $("#userErrors").text("Username must be entered!");
        }
    });

    $("#Password").blur(function(e){
        if ($("#Password").val() == "") {
            $("#passwordErrors").text("Password must be entered!");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It works if you add some content to alert.  The JS engine threw an error because the alert function was being called with no parameters.  I would also recommend binding the event with `document.ready()`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Username").blur(function(e){
        alert("something");
        if ($("#Username").val() == "") {
            $("#userErrors").text("Username must be entered!");
        }
    });
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/PfnGv/

Comment: Sorry, I had the alert in there just to see if it was being hit or not at all.